# Docker Sync won't start after installing Catalina

Tags: docker

After installing Catalina on OSX, my Docker Sync is not working

```
$ docker-sync-stack start
-bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-sync-stack: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I've only found this website, but unclear what is referring to: https://qiita.com/YusukeIwaki/items/241cbf1a3552fd42fb6a

Answer (score 5):

I just installed it again

```
$ sudo gem install docker-sync
```